# AutoSizeTextType uniform crops my textview bottom part

Tags: android, textview

I have such code for textview:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:text="sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="30sp"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="18sp"
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

and it looks on the design:

[image]

after some tests I found that when I remove `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` or change it to `none` my text can fill TextView without cropping. But as I know `app:autoSizeTextType="none"` turns off responsive text size. Maybe I did any mistake in my xml what causes such problem?

Comment: use android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" instead of app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" that should fix your issue.

Comment: @Parmesh, it is bad solution because in such case as I see all test responsivity is turned off

Comment: This issue is happening because of android:layout_height="wrap_content", its better to have some fixed height or more height. I will suggest you to use horizontal guideline and constraint this textview with that guideline (incase you can't give fixed height for this textview).

Comment: can you post any possible solution for this problem for better understanding pls?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions of this problem but below solution might be useful for you.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="18sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:minLines="2"
android:text="sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext"
    android:background="#faa"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="30sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/horizontalGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here you can change the Guideline percent according to your requirement, in this example I have kept 0.1 which is 10% from top of the page.

I hope it will resolve your issue.
Github code link: https://github.com/parmeshtoyou/StackOverflow/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main2.xml